# Can I store Markup within a HTML5 data-attribute tag?

Tags: html, css

I am wondering, if/how I can add Markup to a data-attribute tag? Like:

```
 <i data-description="<h5>Head</h5><p>Content</p>">Foo</i>
```

I am using this info later on (from David Walsh) with:

```
 i:hover::after{content: attr(data-description);}
```

And it outputs the Markup as plain text. Is there any chance I could use Markup-tags in a data-attribute though?

Comment: Basically... **NO** and nor should you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text inside data attribute values will be interpreted like any other text in an attribute value. Markup will be parsed as normal for an attribute value.

You can store any text you like in the attribute. That can include content that you intend to have interpreted as markup in other places (watch out for `&` and `"` characters which will need representing as entities).

You cannot use markup in a CSS pseudo-element. This has nothing to do with where you get it from.